# MySQL drop foreign key constraint and remove NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I alter this table for user_id to drop foreign key and change NOT NULL to NULL

It refers to the user table.

Create table also shown at bottom - (referred to in comments). I'm trying to match the foreign key.

Most importantly as a first step would be to remove the NOT NULL to NULL, but unsure how to do it.

```
mysql> describe post;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_posted | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assigned_to | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reported_by | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe user;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(20)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(120) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| image_file | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| post  | CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reported_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


| user  | CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `image_file` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Do you know what the FK is called - or is that the problem?

Comment: Not DESCRIBE - show CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Thanks, it refers to the id in the user table, which I have added to the question. I'm new to SQL, would the FK be 'id' or the use table itself? Thank you

Comment: my primary concern is to remove the NOT NULL to NULL, secondary is to remove the foreign key

Comment: A describe does not show the FKs please add the output from show create table <tablename> for both tables.

Comment: added to question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `NOT NULL` constraint you can do:

```
alter table post modify user_id int null;
```

Then to drop the foreign key constraint you can do:

```
alter table post drop foreign key `post_ibfk_1`;
```